# Extract date from string in format "DD MMM YYYY"

Tags: php, regex, string, date

I am trying to extract a date from a string variable and was hoping to get some help.

```
$editdate = "Content last modified on 17 May 2011 at 23:13";
```

from this string, I am trying to extract 17 May 2011, please keep in mind that the date will vary and the code needs to be able to extract any date in this format, DD MMM YYYY.

I thought of using preg_match to do this but I couldn't come up with a proper regex pattern that would extract the date properly.

Is this possible to do with regex or should I use a different function?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Regex may be overkill if the string format always starts with `Content last modified on `. Is this the case?

Comment: @jason yes, the string will always contain Content last modified on before the date. I suppose I could try using implode to do this?

Comment: stevecomrie has your answer then. @sdleihssirhc, what?

Comment: @Jason - "Like a Boss" is a good thing :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
$timestamp = strtotime( str_replace( array("Content last modified ", "at"), "", $editdate ) );
```

Which will leave you with an epoch time stamp that you can then output however you like using `date()`

Comment: I guess this is a superb answer:) An out of the box one!:)

Comment: @usr122212 : I had to make an edit because strtotime didn't like the " at ", in the original date. See my updated code.

Comment: hmm this is pretty weird.. with `$timestamp = date( 'j M. Y.', strtotime( str_replace( "Content last modified on ", "", $editdate ) ) );` it returns 31 Dec. 1969 lol that can't be right

Answer (score 3):

This is possible with a regex. Given the format DD MMM YYYY you would need a regex that matches two (or one?) digits, then one space, three letters, one space and four digits.

That would look like:

```
$regex = '/(\d{2} [a-z]{3} \d{4})/i';
```

This can be optimized further.

Comment: This would fail when a date is formatted without a leading zero for the current day. say 1 November 2011 would not match.

Comment: Correct, `\d{2}` needs to be replaced with `\d{1,2}` if you also want to match single digit days.

Comment: Jup that would be the most flexible i guess :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Presuming the textual content of your string is always the same, and that it always ends with the time...

```
$editdate = substr($editdate, 25, -9); // 17 May 2011
```

However, this is very inflexible if the date format were ever to change.

Comment: +1 if your premise is true, this is the better performing way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this 'un:

```
preg_match('/(\d?\d [A-Za-z]+ \d\d\d\d) at (\d\d\:\d\d)/', $editdate, $matches);

print_r($matches); 
$date = $matches[1];
$time = $matches[2];
```

I THINK that'll work in all cases (though it is pretty ugly).... :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be the pattern that does the trick:

```
([0-9]){1}([0-9]){0,1}(\s.*\s)([0-9]){4}
```

Search for 1 digit then there might be another, followed by a space and character, a space and 4 digits for the year.